# Quero que o botao do Whats, apareca so ao rolar a pagina quando chegar a 70% dela. Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

eu estou tentando fazer que o botao do whats, aparece na tela so quando atingir uma porcentagem de scroll da pagina, por exemplo, quando eu rolar o scroll, vai aparecer o botao em 70% de rolagem da pagina. E tambem colocar uma condicao que esse botao apareca em todas as paginas menos as que a URL do site estiver a palavra -cartao- ... Me ajudem to perdido

Por enquanto o que consegui fazer foi isso.

```
<!-- INICIO Botao do whats -->
<script>
   $(document).scroll(function() {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (y > 1000) {
        $('.caixa-whats').fadeIn(2000);
    }`insira o código aqui`
    });
</script>
<style>
    .caixa-whats {
        height: 58px;
        width: 58px;
        background-color: #F5F5F5;
        border-radius: 10px;
        right: 10px;
        bottom: 100px;
        position: fixed;
        border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
        box-shadow: 0 0px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
        display: none;
    }
    @media (max-width: 900px) {
        .caixa-whats {
            bottom: 10px;
        }
    }
</style>
<?php $template_directory = get_template_directory_uri(); ?>
<div class="caixa-whats">
    <a  href="#" target="_blank">
        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/assets/images/logo-whats.png" width="58" height="58" alt="">
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

**RESOLVIDO**

Consegui resolver o problema da seguinte forma..
1- Botao do whats so aparece quando o scroll atingir 70% de rolagem da pagina.
2- O botao aparece em todas as paginas exceto as que tiverem um nome na URL especifico.

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    let s = $(window).scrollTop(),
        d = $(document).height(),
        c = $(window).height();

    let scrollPercent = (s / (d - c)) * 100;
    var text = window.location.href;
    var teste = text.indexOf("campanhas");

    if(scrollPercent >= 70 && teste == -1 ){
            $('.caixa-whats').fadeIn(1000);
            console.log("apareceu");
        }
        else{
            $('.caixa-whats').fadeOut(1000);
            console.log("desapareceu");
        }        
    });
```

Answer (score -3):

Para o código do whatsapp, converter em porcentagem é um pouco mais complicado, mas deve ajudar.

```
<script>

$(window).scroll(function(){
    
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1680) {
        $('.caixa-whats').css({"display": "block", "transition": "1s"});
    } else {
        $('.caixa-whats').css({"display": "none", "transition": "1s"});
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Gabriel, muito obrigado pela ajuda. Eu ate fiz assim, desta forma, mas tem paginas do site que nao tem uma altura de 1680px, ai o botao acaba nao aparecendo, e tbm tem outras que passa de 4000px, a ideia era o botao aparecer logo quando estivesse faltando 400px para chegar no bottom por exemplo.. Mas agradeco a ajuda, Muitoo obrigado!!!

Comment: Tente ver neste link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28052165/jquery-scrolltop-position-to-percentage